# CSS HTML menu unwanted bottom margin when inline-block

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm trying to fix a problem I have with one of my custom theme I am working on.

If you browse to the site http://www.worclan.com/ you will see I have made a drop down menu. When you hover over a menu item or you are on the current page the item turns yellow.

The problem is I can't get the bottom of the yellow to touch the bottom of the containing menu box. There appears to be a added padding or margin which I can't track down and remove.

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: Is the containing menu box an inline block as well?

Comment: Please post the code related to your issue within your question. This allows other users who may have a similar issue at a later point in time to view the code and how it was resolved. There is no guarantee the link will always be the same code.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you need to post the code in your question in your question.

If you set `#navarea` to `line-height:0`, it will work.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: it is the answer and the OP used it.

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou! I would have posted code, but it would have been a ton of code and I presumed anyone on here would just use firebug or similar once on site :)

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful. @user3885612 You should post only the code necessary to reproduce the problem.